# Fake click on a Button at a login Page with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt

I want to login to a Page with QNetworkAccessManager and save than the cookies , to get the source code from a Page , where you have to be logged in. 
With my Code I cann fill up the Inputs on a Page, but I can't clieck the button. 
Can anyone help me please?

In .pro File: 
QT += network

Here is my Code:

file.h:

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QNetworkCookieJar>
#include <QNetworkProxy>

#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrlQuery>
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>

#include <QCoreApplication>

class object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QUrlQuery postData;
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager;
    QUrl serviceUrl;
    QNetworkCookieJar *cookies;
    QNetworkRequest request;

    object(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~object();

    void load();

public slots:
    void finished(QNetworkReply* a);
};
```

file.cpp:

```
#include "networkaccessmanager.h"


object::object(QObject *parent)
    :  QObject(parent)
{

    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    serviceUrl = QUrl("https://*/user/login?redirect_to=");
    cookies = networkManager->cookieJar();
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finished(QNetworkReply*)) );
}

object::~object()
{

}

void object::load()
{
    postData.addQueryItem("user_name", "use");
    postData.addQueryItem("password", "pw");

    request.setUrl(serviceUrl);

    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    networkManager->post(request, postData.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
}

void object::finished(QNetworkReply *a)
{
    std::cout << a->readAll().toStdString() << std::endl;
    QCoreApplication::exit();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

#include "networkaccessmanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    object obj;

    obj.load();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: If Username and Password are correct, int the slot finished a->readAll().toStdString() is nothing and if the Username or Password are not correct a->readAll().toStdString() is the Page Code. I don't know why it is so but it could maby help

Answer (score 0):

I have used the qwebview, what i actually didn't want to use and used this function:

```
int WebView::clickButton(QString inputName /* input[type=submit] */ )
{
    QWebElement button = this->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst(inputName);
    if (button.isNull()) {
        std::cout << "\33[2K\r" << " => Error: Button konnte nicht gefunden werden." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    button.evaluateJavaScript( "this.click()" );
    return 0;
}
```